# Can't access CSS some style fields from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a reason why I can do this:

```
document.getElementById('gridID').style.background='blue';
```

but when I try this:

```
document.getElementById('gridID').style.background-color='blue';
```

throws this:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I need to access backgroundPosition and some other things and they just aren't working. They do not appear in xcode's autosuggest when I type and they do not work when I try them anyways. Any thoughts? I haven't found similar problems on Google to my surprise.

Thanks,
Chet.

Comment: It may be worth noting that gridID is the id for a div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript identifiers cannot contain `-`s.

Instead, use camelCase:

```
document.getElementById('gridID').style.backgroundColor='blue';
```

Comment: Not true, actually - `myObject['background-color']` is perfectly valid. But you can't use `-` in dot notation, because it is interpreted as a minus sign.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: True, although that won't actually do anything.  Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
document.getElementById('gridID').style.backgroundColor='blue';
```

for styles that have more than one word (like `background-color`)  JS uses `camelCased` names instead of `dash-separated` names,